# How to create an equivalent circuit model for the excitation in HFSS EM field calculation?

Tags: voltage, circuit-analysis, simulation, electromagnetism

I am new to circuit simulation, and now got stuck in the problem of modeling the excitation when transforming a electromagnetic field calculation problem into a circuit calculation. I would appreciate it a lot if someone could give advice on it.

Assume I have a device with two ports, and I have modelled the device itself into a two-port non-linear network, i.e., with the ports' voltages, I could calculate the currents through some numerical methods.

When using this device in reality, we will add an excitation into one port, say port A, and connect the other port, say port B, with a matched resistor. I want to simulate the reverse electrical field/voltage at port A.

Modeling port B into a circuit is easy. However, in my limited experience with circuit simulation, I have no idea on how to model the excitation in port A. In fact, the excitation in port A, in the language of field calculation, is an input electrical field E0, which is not equal to the total electrical field at that port. Thus I could not get the total voltage at port A.

Does anyone know how to describe the circuit? Any advice or reference will help a lot.